# IntelliJ (IDEA/Webstorm) ignore/accept custom templating tags in HTML documents

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, templating

I am using custom seperators/tags for template variables in HTML code. My tags are "{[{" "}]}". Can I make IntelliJ IDEA (or WebStorm) ignore completely what is inbetween them? If it matters, it is Go template language with custom tags.

Example :

```
<div title="{[{.T.T "error"}]}!"></div>
```

Gets marked as error because of the quotes inside the quotes. It also disables the ability for proper auto indentation or code formatting.

Another example, in this case JavaScript in an HTML document :

```
<script>
    {[{if .Data.User}]}
        var userData = {[{.Data.User}]};
    {[{end}]}
</script>
```

This marks the quotes themselves as error.

I don't want IntelliJ to check the template code, just ignoring everything between the brackets would be enough.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work this way in this IDE... It's either proper support for templating engine (via plugin) or errors for current language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. IntelliJ IDEA builds a complete parse tree for the entire file, and it is not able to ignore arbitrary chunks of the file.

What you can do is either write a plugin that will be able to parse your template syntax, or change the syntax you use so that it matches more closely an existing template library already supported by IntelliJ IDEA.